# [C][Java] Good practises for a function that reads EITHER a row or column of a 2D array?

Tags: function, methods

Very often I come across these kinds of situations where I have lots of exceptions and/or the function arguments don't make much sense or can cause errors if the programmer doesn't know exactly how the function works. This is kind of one of those situations so I thought I should ask the stack for some advice.

I have a 2D matrix and I want to make a function that reads EITHER part of a row or part of a column. This is kind of easy. I can either split them up into two functions, like

`readCol(int row, int startCol, int endCol)` **and** `readRow(int col, int startRow, int endRow)`

or just keep all of it in one function like

`readLine(char 'axis', int start, int end)`

**or**

`readLine(int startRow, int endRow, int startCol, int endCol)`.

However, none of these seem like the best way to do this.

For example, the first functions have no exceptions. Just loop and read. However, they contain pretty much the identical code, the only difference being that row and col are switched.

Using the second option, I get what I feel is "ugly" code. I would need an if-statements and make two separate cases depending on whether I want to read a row or a column.

The third option is kind of good, but since I only want to read ONE line, it would allow for the person using the function to read multiple lines, which could cause errors or unexpected behavior.

Maybe this seems like nitpicking, but if there are two things I've been told about writing good code, it is to make it as understandable as possible, and to not repeat code when you don't have to. I feel like all of these functions kind of slightly violates those rules.

So, any ideas for how to tackle these types of functions? This particular example is of course not a big deal, but when the functions get larger, things can easily turn into spaghetti.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use all three functions!

```
// read one row
public double readRow( int row, int startCol, int endCol ) {
    readSubarray( row, row, startCol, endCol );
}

// read one column
public double readCol( int col, int startRow, int endRow ) {
    return readSubarray( startRow, endRow, col, col );
}

private double readSubarray( int startRow, int endRow, int startCol, int endCol ) {
    //...
}
```

Make the two `readRow` and `readCol` functions `public`, then have a third `private` function that reads a subarray of the original 2d array.

No duplicate code; readable interface.  The pattern is that your public interface is friendly and specific, and is backed by a private, more general purpose  function.

Note: I'm assuming your start/end row/col variables are inclusive, and you're returning something like a `double` - the language above is Java-ish.

Comment: Haha, I didn't think of that, thank you! I'll accept your answer in a day unless someone comes up with an even better solution.